# multiple functions onClick() not working

Tags: javascript

Below is the code that I used for multiple java scripts on a single button. But only any one is working when I disable the second one. Please let me know: how do I change my code to make it to work fine?

```
function invoke(but)  
{  
if(but==0)   
    {  
        function move(){  
        document.getElementById('tgt1').value = 
        document.getElementById('Allocation').value;  
        document.getElementById('Allocation').value="";  
        document.getElementById("Send").disabled=true;  

    }document.myform.action="Alloc_Insert.do";  
    }  
           else if(but==1)  
   {  
       document.myform.action="";  
   }  

else if(but==2){ document.myform.action="WL_Verif.do";}  
else if(but==3){ document.myform.action="Add_Query.do";}  
document.myform.submit();  
        }
```

And the html is as below:

```
<input type="Submit" value="Allocate" id="Send" name="submit" onClick="invoke(0);move();"/><br/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the name of the button to something else than "submit"

---

To explain what happens:

When you assign the name-attribute "submit" to the button(or any other form-element), this element will be accessible via

```
document.myform.submit
```

but there is also the build-in method of a form: `submit()`, you also may access it by using

```
document.myform.submit
```

What happens now when you call    `document.myform.submit()`

I'll write the code a little bit different, and you will see trouble:

```
document.myform['submit']()
```

Instead of accessing the built-in method, the code points first to the form-element, and then tries to execute the method. But a form-element is not a method, it all ends up in an error and the rest of the script(including the call of move() ) will not get executed.

It's the same with "reset", you never should use the name of a built-in property/method of the form-element as name for form-elements.

Answer (score 1):

notice the 'move' function is not declared outside the 'invoke' function.

Then;

either wrap them in a self invoking function:

```
onclick="(function(){ invoke(0);move(); })();"
```

or attach event handlers (preferred usually)

```
div.attachEventListener('click', function () { ... }); // DOM 3
div.attachEvent('click', function () { ... }); // IE
```

Comment: change the name of the button to something else than "submit"

Comment: change the name of the button to something else than "submit" this worked. thanks for all of you buddies to give me some solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your functions are declared in a weird way. You're defining `move` *inside of* `invoke`, which I don't think you want. If you want to have two functions, put `move` *outside* of `invoke`, like this:

```
function move(){
  document.getElementById('tgt1').value =
    document.getElementById('Allocation').value;
  document.getElementById('Allocation').value="";
  document.getElementById("Send").disabled=true;
}

function invoke(but)
{
  if(but==0)
  {
    move();
    document.myform.action="Alloc_Insert.do";
  }
  else if(but==1)
  {
    document.myform.action="";
  }
  else if(but==2){ document.myform.action="WL_Verif.do";}
  else if(but==3){ document.myform.action="Add_Query.do";}
  document.myform.submit();
}
```

A note: it's generally not a good idea to use `onClick` in your HTML -- it's better to put that in your JavaScript.

Comment: Hi buddy, Thanks for your reply , here only 1 function is working i.e. invoke but move() is not.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the scope of the `move()` function. Try defining `move` outside of invoke.

```
function invoke (but) {  
    if(but==0) {
        document.myform.action="Alloc_Insert.do";
        // I don't know if you meant to call move() here or not
    }
    else if (but==2) { document.myform.action="WL_Verif.do"; } 
    else if (but==3) { document.myform.action="Add_Query.do"; }

    document.myform.submit();  
}

function move(){  
    document.getElementById('tgt1').value = 
    document.getElementById('Allocation').value;  
    document.getElementById('Allocation').value="";  
    document.getElementById("Send").disabled=true;
}
```

Also, properly formatting your code will do wonders to the legibility of it.

NOTE: Firefox seems to be quite happy to execute the `onClick="invoke(0);move();"` even if `move` is defined inside `invoke`. Chrome however won't execute `move` because it can't find it. So be sure to test your script in multiple browsers as well.